# WP7 WebBrowser - stop page rendering

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, browser

i need some advice for handling a Stop function for my browser.
it must be caused by a buttonclick, so i think i will need javascript to solve this problem.
Somebody already faced this issue?

greets
roqstr

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop"?

Comment: if you're trying to stop navigation inside a webbrowser, just override Navigating after the initial page you want has LoadCompleted, and e.Cancel the NavigationArgs.

Comment: @willmel: is it possible to access the active "navigating" method, to set a e.cancel = true?

Comment: @Pekka i want to cancel the active navigation-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**what's working fine:**

```
private void cancel_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.execCommand('Stop');");
    }
```

thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

                //wb is the webbrowser
                wb.LoadCompleted += new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(wb_LoadCompleted);

//pretty sure you need this somewhere other than the constructor, or you'll get that 
//"cannot navigate until in visual tree" exception
wb.NavigateToString(MyHTMLString);
            }

        void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            wb.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(wb_Navigating);
        }

        void wb_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

The idea is basically that. override `LoadCompleted`, and after the page you want to load loads, make sure that no other page can be navigated to by setting `e.Cancel` inside the `Navigating` event.

Comment: i don't think this is working, because it won't interrupt ALL navigating-processes with 1 e.cancel = true;
only the wb_Navigating event will be canceled, but the first navigating process will go on.
And i don't want to take the option to navigate after i pressed the key, i just want to cancel this 1 active process.

Comment: example: user1 navigates to bing.com,
user1 navigates to bing-maps, but decides to cancel this navigation while it's in progress.
cancel-key is pressed, the wb stops working at the current point and is avaiable for new commands.

that was the idea.